# Android/JAVA: Async functions call to avoid blocking calls

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, blocking

In my Android app, there's a function called `userProfile(Promise promise)` which looks similar as below:

```
@ReactMethod
public void userProfile(Promise promise) {
    String name = getName();
    String number = getNumber();
    String userDynamicId = getHttpDynamicId(); // network request
    ...
    promise.resolve(name + number + userDynamicId);
}
```

The userProfile is a `ReactMethod` which will be handled by UI thread, however, `getHttpDynamicId()` may cost long time due to the networking. Sometimes, the UI thread is blocked by this function.

Is there any easy way to using another thread to handler `getHttpDynamicId()` to avoid the GUI freezes? Or any other multi thread way to handle the problem?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/best-background

Comment: @MeowCat2012  Thanks for the documents, it's helpful. I'm looking at it right now. I will paste my solution here if I can work it out. If so, could you please help give a thumb up to counteract the '-1'. It's sad to see people gives the '-1' so easily without a reason.

Comment: Well, OK for this time. You could learn to `search` for existing solutions before asking a question, and browsing `Documentation|Reference|Online Courses|Tutorials` in the future. Not only saving others' time but also saving your own time. However as a beginner it's even hard to know where to start searching (e.g. what keyword to use, how to describe) so I do not think it really reasonable to vote down.

Comment: @MeowCat2012 Thanks for your understanding and also the link. I've managed to solve it. Will upload my solution later. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

From the link which Meow provided: https://developer.android.com/training/best-background. I managed to come up with the solution.

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() {
        String userDynamicId = "";
        try {
           // XXXXX Code to get ID
        } catch (Exception e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
        return userDynamicId;
    }
}

@ReactMethod
public void userProfile(Promise promise) {
    String name = getName();
    String number = getNumber();
    // instantiate MyCallable
    // Create executor and use Future to get the result from call()
    promise.resolve(name + number + userDynamicId);
}
```